# error while indexing by rows data.table with column containing interval object from package lubridate

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, intervals, lubridate

I have data like this (changed to protect original data):

```
View(dose_merged)

SUBJECT_Blinded PACKID  SACDPDAT    SACRTDAT    treatment_interval  TS_SDAT TS_EDAT     SD_SDAT SD_EDAT
1   1201201 10096   2012-04-25  2010-04-22  58  NA  NA  2011-01-03  2013-01-02
2   1101401 10595   2012-01-03  2010-02-31  28  NA  NA  2011-01-03  2013-01-02
3   1201001 10971   2011-11-04  2010-02-03  60  NA  NA  2011-01-03  2013-01-02
4   1201001 12592   2012-03-01  2010-02-25  55  NA  NA  2011-01-03  2013-01-02
```

With columns types in data table:

```
> mapply(class, dose_merged)
$SUBJECT_Blinded
[1] "numeric"

$PACKID
[1] "numeric"

$SACDPDAT
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$SACRTDAT
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$treatment_interval
[1] "Interval"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"

$SD_SDAT

[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$SD_EDAT
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I am trying to index by rows, for example:

```
dose_merged[10:15,]
```

Then, I get error message:

```
Error in format(x@start, tz = x@tzone, usetz = TRUE) : 
trying to get slot "start" from an object (class "Interval") that is not an S4 object
```

What's going on? :)

The first 4 rows of dput(dose_merge):

```
 structure(list(SUBJECT_Blinded = c(2222001, 2201001, 2201001, 
 2222022), PACKID = c(10096, 10595, 10971, 12592), SACDPDAT = structure(c(1335304800, 
 1325545200, 1320361200, 1330556400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
 ), tzone = ""), SACRTDAT = structure(c(1340316000, 1327964400, 
 1325545200, 1335304800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
treatment_interval = structure(c(58, 28, 60, 55), class = structure("Interval", package = "lubridate")), 
TS_SDAT = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TS_EDAT = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), SD_SDAT = structure(c(1325545200, 1325545200, 
1325545200, 1325545200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
SD_EDAT = structure(c(1357081200, 1357081200, 1357081200, 
1357081200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("SUBJECT_Blinded", 
"PACKID", "SACDPDAT", "SACRTDAT", "treatment_interval", "TS_SDAT", 
"TS_EDAT", "SD_SDAT", "SD_EDAT"), sorted = "SUBJECT_Blinded", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000300788>)
```

Comment: Can you provide a some/all of your data, `dput(dose_merged)` and paste it into the question.

Comment: Yes, I added the data you asked about.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, but you only provided 2 rows of data. Can you produce 15 rows since this is the command that you say creates the error.  Also, can you add at lease 15 rows to your view command?

Comment: Hovewer, I get error also by writing for example dose_merged[1:2,], so maybe I'll add only two more rows ( I have to modify them to protect the original data..) What is strange, command dput(dose_merged[1:15],"dose_merged_copy2") works !

Comment: I am also having this problem, and have not found a solution . . . did you ever figure it out?